# How to test if a font is installed using VBA?

Tags: vba, fonts

What is the easiest way to check if a particular font is installed using VBA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, true to form I found a solution 30 seconds after posting this. This is despite a 10 minute search before resorting to SO....

### List installed fonts

The procedure listed below displays a list of installed fonts in Column A of the active worksheet. It uses the `FindControl` method to locate the Font control on the Formatting toolbar. If this control is not found (i.e. it was removed by the user) a temporary CommandBar is created and the Font control is added to it.

```vb
Sub ShowInstalledFonts()
    Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)

    'If Font control is missing, create a temp CommandBar
    If FontList Is Nothing Then
        Set TempBar = Application.CommandBars.Add
        Set FontList = TempBar.Controls.Add(ID:=1728)
    End If

    'Put the fonts into column A
    Range("A:A").ClearContents
    For i = 0 To FontList.ListCount - 1
        Cells(i + 1, 1) = FontList.List(i + 1)
    Next i

    'Delete temp CommandBar if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    TempBar.Delete
End Sub
```

### Is a font installed?

The function below uses the same technique as the ShowInstalledFonts procedure. It returns True if a specified font is installed.

```
Function FontIsInstalled(sFont) As Boolean
    'Returns True if sFont is installed
    FontIsInstalled = False
    Set FontList = Application.CommandBars("Formatting").FindControl(ID:=1728)

    'If Font control is missing, create a temp CommandBar
    If FontList Is Nothing Then
        Set TempBar = Application.CommandBars.Add
        Set FontList = TempBar.Controls.Add(ID:=1728)
    End If

    For i = 0 To FontList.ListCount - 1
        If FontList.List(i + 1) = sFont Then
            FontIsInstalled = True
            On Error Resume Next
            TempBar.Delete
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

    'Delete temp CommandBar if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    TempBar.Delete
End Function
```

The statement below demonstrates how to use this function in a VBA procedure. It displays True in a message box if the user's system contains the Comic Sans MS font.

```
MsgBox FontIsInstalled("Comic Sans MS")
```

The above was originally at [this URL](http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip79.htm), retrieved from the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20090425082949/http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip79.htm) on 2020-02-05.

Comment: It's a much more elegant solution without the use of APIs.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: Link is gone. It should be same as this: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/getting_a_list_of_installed_fonts/

Comment: I have found this approach to be unreliable in Excel 2016

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20090425082949/http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip79.htm

Answer (score 11):

http://www.vbcity.com/forums/topic.asp?tid=57012
redirects to
http://vbcity.com/forums/t/55257.aspx

This vb6 code is compatible with VBA:

```
Function FontIsInstalled(sFont As String) As Boolean
    '' This reference should already be set by default
    '' Tools > References > OLE Automation
    Dim NewFont As StdFont
    On Error Resume Next
    Set NewFont = New StdFont
    With NewFont
        ' Assign the proposed font name
        ' Will not be assigned if font doesn't exist
        .Name = sFont
        ' Return true if font assignment succeded
        FontIsInstalled = (StrComp(sFont, .Name, vbTextCompare) = 0)
        ' return actual font name through arguments
        sFont = .Name
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This works fine, and is much more reliable than the commonly used approach that captures the Font selection control on the old command bar system (NOT the one on the ribbon).

Answer (score 2):

using apis there are

EnumFonts
The EnumFonts function enumerates the fonts available on a specified device. For each font with the specified typeface name, the EnumFonts function retrieves information about that font and passes it to the application-defined callback function. This callback function can process the font information as desired. Enumeration continues until there are no more fonts or the callback function returns zero.

VB4-32,5,6

```
Declare Function EnumFonts Lib "gdi32" Alias "EnumFontsA" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal lpsz As String, ByVal lpFontEnumProc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

or

The EnumFontFamilies function enumerates the fonts in a specified font family that are available on a specified device. This function supersedes the EnumFonts function.

VB4-32,5,6

```
Declare Function EnumFontFamilies Lib "gdi32" Alias "EnumFontFamiliesA" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal lpszFamily As String, ByVal lpEnumFontFamProc As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
```

example routine

```
'In a module
Public Const NTM_REGULAR = &H40&
Public Const NTM_BOLD = &H20&
Public Const NTM_ITALIC = &H1&
Public Const TMPF_FIXED_PITCH = &H1
Public Const TMPF_VECTOR = &H2
Public Const TMPF_DEVICE = &H8
Public Const TMPF_TRUETYPE = &H4
Public Const ELF_VERSION = 0
Public Const ELF_CULTURE_LATIN = 0
Public Const RASTER_FONTTYPE = &H1
Public Const DEVICE_FONTTYPE = &H2
Public Const TRUETYPE_FONTTYPE = &H4
Public Const LF_FACESIZE = 32
Public Const LF_FULLFACESIZE = 64
Type LOGFONT
   lfHeight As Long
   lfWidth As Long
   lfEscapement As Long
   lfOrientation As Long
   lfWeight As Long
   lfItalic As Byte
   lfUnderline As Byte
   lfStrikeOut As Byte
   lfCharSet As Byte
   lfOutPrecision As Byte
   lfClipPrecision As Byte
   lfQuality As Byte
   lfPitchAndFamily As Byte
   lfFaceName(LF_FACESIZE) As Byte
End Type
Type NEWTEXTMETRIC
   tmHeight As Long
   tmAscent As Long
   tmDescent As Long
   tmInternalLeading As Long
   tmExternalLeading As Long
   tmAveCharWidth As Long
   tmMaxCharWidth As Long
   tmWeight As Long
   tmOverhang As Long
   tmDigitizedAspectX As Long
   tmDigitizedAspectY As Long
   tmFirstChar As Byte
   tmLastChar As Byte
   tmDefaultChar As Byte
   tmBreakChar As Byte
   tmItalic As Byte
   tmUnderlined As Byte
   tmStruckOut As Byte
   tmPitchAndFamily As Byte
   tmCharSet As Byte
   ntmFlags As Long
   ntmSizeEM As Long
   ntmCellHeight As Long
   ntmAveWidth As Long
End Type
Declare Function EnumFontFamilies Lib "gdi32" Alias "EnumFontFamiliesA" (ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal lpszFamily As String, ByVal lpEnumFontFamProc As Long, LParam As Any) As Long
Function EnumFontFamProc(lpNLF As LOGFONT, lpNTM As NEWTEXTMETRIC, ByVal FontType As Long, LParam As Long) As Long
   Dim FaceName As String
  'convert the returned string to Unicode
   FaceName = StrConv(lpNLF.lfFaceName, vbUnicode)
  'print the form on Form1
   Form1.Print Left$(FaceName, InStr(FaceName, vbNullChar) - 1)
  'continue enumeration
   EnumFontFamProc = 1
End Function

'In a form
Private Sub Form_Load()
   'KPD-Team 2000
   'URL: http://www.allapi.net/
   'E-Mail: KPDTeam@Allapi.net
   Dim hDC As Long
   'set graphics mode to persistent
   Me.AutoRedraw = True
   'enumerates the fonts
   EnumFontFamilies Me.hDC, vbNullString, AddressOf EnumFontFamProc, ByVal 0&
End Sub
```