# Direct use of ttf/otf fontfile in Ms Access

Tags: ms-access

How can I, if possible, use a fontfile (ttf/otf) in Ms Access, without installing it as font in Windows?

If I use a custom font, I can't be sure, that the user has install the font.

Comment: You can check if it is installed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170468/how-to-test-if-a-font-is-installed-using-vba, if not ask user to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Somehow the font must be installed first. 
That may even require admin rights.

If a font is not present, a close (installed) replacement font will be used

Comment: Thank you. All informations I found so far about that topic are similar to you answer.